# VS2010 extension for displaying type definition on hover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I used to have an extension which made it so that when you hover over a variable or a type in the code editor, a popup would show the type definition (similar to the class view and object explorer) as well as allowing you to navigate to derived types, base types, generic parameter types, etc.

Does anyone know which extension I'm talking about? Or know of a similar one? I've looked all over VS Gallery :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think I have the same and I have only installed DPack and PowerTools from MS on my VS 2010 box.

Comment: Ah, it was PowerTools that provided it, but for some reason you must have the solution navigator enabled to get the hover feature. Thanks for the help! :)